# Returning JSON from PHP into Array

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

I want to take the returning JSON object and display what the PHP query returned, but when I use brackets to access the indices value it displays only one character at a time. Basically I want each index to contain each row from the query. This particular query has two results (the id and file name). I would like to get both the id and name into one index of the JSON array. Output displayed below:

```
7 5.jpg
8 7-mini.jpg
```

Here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: '<?php echo base_url().'jqueryDB/jquery';?>',   
      type:'POST',      
      dataType: 'json',    
      success: function(output_string){
                document.write(output_string[0]);
      }
    });

  });
```

Right now this display '7', instead of '7 5.jpg'. How can I get it to store each row into one index?

Here's my PHP file:

```
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('id');   
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM upload WHERE userID = '.$userID);
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows();
    $val = $query->row_array();    

    $output_string = "";  

    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $output_string .= $row->id;
        $output_string .= " ".$row->name."<br />";
    }

    echo json_encode($output_string);
```

Comment: I would use PARSE instead of dataType  ... `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(your_var);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
...
$output = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  $output[] = $row->id . ' ' . $row->name;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you want to store the results of your query into an array, *not* a string.  The results of calling `json_encode` will take that array and turn it into a JSON-encoded string.

```
$output_array = array();

foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $output_array[] = array( 'id' => $row->id, 'name' => $row->name );
}

echo json_encode( $output_array );
```

Notice that the array you pass it can be arbitrarily deep.  `json_encode` will structure the object based off of the structure of the array.  I would also suggest looking at the resultant string in your browser to see what the JSON looks like when encoding multidimensional arrays like this.

In your javascript, you must *parse* the string to get it to be a useful JavaScript object...

```
success: function(output_string){
    var obj = JSON.parse( output_string );
    // This will iterate over all of the values in the return object
    for(var i in obj) {
        document.write(obj[i].name + '<br>' + obj[i].id);
    }
}
```

Feel free to structure your return object differently, I was just going off of what you laid out in your question.

jQuery also has facilities where, if you specify your MIME types correctly, the parameter to your `success` callback will automatically be parsed into a JSON object for you.  For more information see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: This is probably the better answer :) Mine just gets you quickly to the end of the line, watcher gave you useful details beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote most of this before @watcher's answer came up and it's probably the one you want but this was written already so I figured I post it.  I'd modify @David Fells solution like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($query->result() AS $row) {
  $output[$row->id] = array();

  foreach ($row AS $prop=>$value) {
    $output[$row->id][$prop] = $value;
  }
}

$output_json = json_encode($output);
```

I generally use PDO objects for accessing my DBs and that returns an array instead of object.  This should work for an array but I believe it will work with objects in PHP as well.

This should work with any query that returns a column named id and obviously the id portion could be replaced with $id where $id equals whatever id string/integer you'd like use.

...

Now when you want the array back in PHP (I'm not particularly familiar with 
javascript) you would need to use:

```
// The TRUE returns it as an array rather than object.
$output = json_decode($output_json, TRUE);
```

Much of this is pretty basic and I imagine you know it already.  But the title made me think that the this last part - the json_decode part - was what you needed and maybe it will help someone else who finds this question.